# Json deserialization with @JsonTypeInfo not working on consumer side

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have problem with json deserialization on consumer side. When I try to consume message I am getting

```
org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided
```

In order to prevent **TypeId** header sending/processing I've added both spring.json.add.type.headers=false and spring.json.use.type.headers=false properties but nothing changed.

I have an example of my classes that I send through kafka:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public abstract class TaskDto {

    @NotNull
    private final UUID taskId;
}

@Data
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Jacksonized
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class SimpleTaskDto extends TaskDto {

    @NotNull
    private final Map<String, Object> data;
}
```

I expect that json deserialization should use @class property in order to determine the actual class, but it looks like I am missing something important here. Should I use spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.value.type.method property to define custom type determination method?

Answer (score 0):

You must configure an `ObjectMapper` respectively:

```
StdTypeResolverBuilder typer = new TypeResolverBuilder(DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING,
            mapper.getPolymorphicTypeValidator());
typer = typer.init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, null);
typer = typer.inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

mapper.setDefaultTyping(typer);
```

Comment: Artem, thank you for your answer. Now I'm getting "Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'" error. Kafka Tool shows that payload has '@class' property but it is not used by converter to parse it.